# Material-UI: Expand Accordion by clicking the icon only

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, accordion, modern-ui

I have created an Accordion for my Project. But I want the panel to be expanded only when the expand icon is clicked. Currently it is expanding on clicking anywhere on the panel. Can we customize its expanding behavior ?

CODE:

```
import React from "react";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import Accordion from "@material-ui/core/Accordion";
import AccordionDetails from "@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import AccordionSummary from "@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary";

export default function App() {
return (
    <div style={{}}>
    <h4>How to create Accordion in ReactJS?</h4>
    <Accordion style={{ width: 400}}>
        <AccordionSummary 
         expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
         aria-controls="panel1a-content"
        >   
          <div>Click to Expand</div>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
        <Typography>Greetings of the day :)</Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
    </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes we can do it like this

**1- Create our own state with handler:**

```
  const [expand, setExpand] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleAcordion = () => {
    setExpand((prev) => !prev);
  };
```

**2- Add our state to the Accordion:**

`<Accordion expanded={expand} style={{ width: 400 }}>`

**3- Add `onClick` for the icon:**

```
    <AccordionSummary
      expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      aria-controls="panel1a-content"
      IconButtonProps={{
        onClick: toggleAcordion
      }}
    >
```

**Full Code:**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**EDIT: Explanation:** Material-UI Accordion has its own state (open or close) and its own click handler, what we did above is that we create our own state and override Material-UI Accordion state by the prop `expanded` and add event listener `onClick` to the icon button by the prop `IconButtonProps`, our event listener will open or close the Accordion by change our state.

**NOTE:** The code above doesn't change the style in case of the cursor pointer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It worked !!!
Can you please give an explanation of how it is working..

Comment: @Aishwarya sure, I added explanation to the answer, I hope it's clear for you.

Comment: got it.. Thanks..

Comment: For v5, see my answer

Answer (score 9):

There is no public API to do what you want out-of-the-box, but you can use this [CSS trick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

**V5**

```
<AccordionSummary
  sx={{
    pointerEvents: "none"
  }}
  expandIcon={
    <ExpandMoreIcon
      sx={{
        pointerEvents: "auto"
      }}
    />
  }
>
```

**V4**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  summary: {
    pointerEvents: 'none',
  },
  icon: {
    pointerEvents: 'auto',
  },
});
```

```
<AccordionSummary
  className={classes.summary}
  expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon className={classes.icon} />}
>
  <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
</AccordionSummary>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: We have API, check this out https://v4.mui.com/api/accordion-summary/ and https://v4.mui.com/api/accordion/

Comment: What I meant is that there is not a simple prop like `expandOnButtonClick`, but yeah, it's doable if you control the `Accordion` state, I'll edit my answer. @Abdulmuhaymin

Answer (score 6):

For v5, and setting the mouse cursor properly:

**1- Create our own state with handler:**

```
const [accordionOpen, setAccordionOpen] = React.useState(false);
```

**2- Add our state to the Accordion and toggle on click:**

```
<Accordion expanded={accordionOpen}>
    <AccordionSummary
      expandIcon={
        <ExpandMoreIcon
          style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
          onClick={() => setAccordionOpen(!accordionOpen)} />
      }
      sx={{ cursor: 'unset !important' }}
    >
```

Comment: So one needs this hack to add on change on icon? Can you elaborate more on how and why your solution works please?

Answer (score 1):

you can try set expanded true/false in the Accordion

```js
function Container(props) {
  const [expand, setExpand] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleAccordion = () => {
    setExpand((prev) => !prev);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Accordion expanded={expand}>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon
            onClick={toggleAccordion}
          />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography></Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </React.Fragment>)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me. I handled it with the [`e.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method, using it in the `onClick` event of the icon after calling the toggle function.

Like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import Accordion from "@material-ui/core/Accordion";
import AccordionDetails from "@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import AccordionSummary from "@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary";

export default function App() {
return (
    <div style={{}}>
    <h4>How to create Accordion in ReactJS?</h4>
    <Accordion style={{ width: 400}}>
        <AccordionSummary 
         expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
         aria-controls="panel1a-content"
        >   
          <div ><img src='yourIcon' onClick={(e) => { toggleAccordion(); e.stopPropagation() }} /></div>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
        <Typography>Greetings of the day :)</Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
    </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way using the onChange property in Accordion (TS version):

```
interface Props {
  data: {id: number, name: string, detail: string}
}
const YourComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ data }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState<number | false>(false) 

  const handleExpand = (id: number) => (_e: React.SyntheticEvent, isExpanded: boolean) => {
  setExpanded(isExpanded ? id : false)
}

return (
  <>
    <Accordion expanded={expanded === data.id} onChange={handleExpand(data.id)}>
      <AccordionSummary
        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>}
      >
        {data.name}
      </AccordionSummary>
      <AccordionDetails>
        {data.detail}
      </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
  </>
 )
}
```