# How to add more action icons to material UI accordion?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, react-bootstrap

[image]

I want to achieve something like in the above picture. Apart from down arrow (collapse) , I want to **add an edit and a delete icon** as well. How can I achieve this?  Here is some code for material UI accordion.

```
export default function SimpleAccordion() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
          sx={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}
        >
          <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>

        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel2a-content"
          id="panel2a-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion 2</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion disabled>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel3a-content"
          id="panel3a-header"
        >
          <Typography>Disabled Accordion</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You tagged both material-ui and react-bootstrap here. So what kind of Accordion are you using? Why are you mixing two UI widget libs anyway?

Comment: Whichever way it is possible is fine. I would prefer material tho.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in Boxes and style them as follows:

```
     <Accordion>
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <AccordionSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls="panel1a-content"
            id="panel2a-header"
            sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
          >
            <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <Box>
            <IconButton>
              <EditIcon onClick={() => alert("Edit Me!")} />
            </IconButton>

            <IconButton>
              <DeleteIcon onClick={() => alert("Delete Me!") />
            </IconButton>
          </Box>
        </Box>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
```

That's it!

You can add more futures to your expandIcon by using `fragments`:

```
 expandIcon = {
    <>
      <IconButton>
        <ExpandMoreIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </>
  }
```

If you want the accordion to expand by clicking either edit or delete button, you need to [add your own state with handler.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69358781/material-ui-expand-accordion-by-clicking-the-icon-only)

Here as an example I've added the expand feature to `edit` button. First add the state and handle:

```
const [expand, setExpand] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleAccordion = () => {
    setExpand((prev) => !prev);
  };
```

And in Accordion:

```
    <Accordion expanded={expand}>
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <AccordionSummary
            iconbuttonprops={{ onClick: toggleAcordion }}
            onClick={() => toggleAccordion()}
            expandIcon={
              <>
                <IconButton>
                  <ExpandMoreIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </>
            }
            aria-controls="panel1a-content"
            id="panel2a-header"
            sx={{
              flexGrow: 1,
            }}
          >
            <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <Box>
            <IconButton
                IconButtonProps={{ onClick: toggleAccordion }}
                onClick={() => toggleAccordion()}
            >
              <EditIcon/>
            </IconButton>

            <IconButton>
              <DeleteIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Box>
        </Box>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
```